# Linq Where value is in Array

Tags: c#, linq

```
IEnumerable<string> periods = new string[] {"ABC", "JKD", "223A"};

var someData = from p in returns  
               from d in p.ReturnDet  
               where p.Year > 2009 
               where d.Period <is in periods array>
```

How do I select values where the d.periods are contained in the periods array?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use the [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx) method.

```
var someData = from p in returns   
               from d in p.ReturnDet   
               where p.Year > 2009  
               where periods.Contains(d.Period);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var someData = from p in returns  
      from d in p.ReturnDet  
                where p.Year > 2009 
                where periods.Contains(d.Period)
```